# Pass data from nested Components Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have a component where with a *ngFor print some boxes defined in an other component like this:

```
<div>
 <commponentB *ngFor="let a of list"></componentB>
</div>
```

where "list" is a list ok object like this:

```
this.list=[{"id":"3","nome":"app3","posizione":3},{"id":"1","nome":"app1","posizione":1},{"id":"2","nome":"app2","posizione":2}];
```

I have to populate all the component. How can I transfer data from this two component?

TY

EDIT1:

the problem is that the list is splitted into 2 list for the repeat in 2 different bootstrap columns so the situation is this:

```
<div>
 <commponentB *ngFor="let a of list1"></componentB>
</div>
<div>
 <commponentB *ngFor="let a of list2"></componentB>
</div>
```

and the component is like that:

```
<div>
<span>{{name}}</span>
</div>
```

if I pass all the list I can't know how to populate the component at the right position (sorry if I don't explain the problem very well)

Answer (score 0):

Since your components are directly linked, you can use the `@Input()` component interaction to send data from the parent to the child.

Here is a link from the official documentation :

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

---

If you can't do that model because of a router interaction, or components are too "far" away so it's too much work to setup several inputs, you can use a shared service to share the data from one to another component.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: I tried like you say but the problem is a little bit different

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass your list to componentB you can define Input() property in componentB and then pass your list

```
<div>
 <commponentB [list]="list"></componentB>
</div>

export class ComponentB{

@Input() list: any[];

}
```

**Update** Ok maybe I'm not getting your issue, even if you have to pass different inputs to same component you can do that. Check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WWwTDZfWPGHUW1wtdD2u?p=preview):

Comment: I tried like you say but the problem is a little bit different